# How to fix 'Unable the find the project that contains {path}' when running c# code in VScode

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, c#-devkit

How to fix 'Unable the find the project that contains {path}' when running c# code in VScode.

I have recently created a new c# project using

```
dotnet new console
```

But when running using the run button in the top left, I get a warning message saying
'Unable to find the project that contains {file path}' , source: c# Dev Kit

I am able to run programs created more than 2 days ago, but I cannot create new ones.

Using dotnet run works, and the program runs as intended but neither running with the run button works nor automatic error highlighting.

Comment: What OS are you running this on?

Comment: Running on the Linux VM within ChromeOS

Comment: Does this help? https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/1802lpi/unable_to_find_the_project_that_contains_error/

Comment: No, I already tried this and it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Did you create launch.json and tasks.json files?

`launch.json` is used to launch an app for debugging. E.g

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/YourConsoleApp/bin/Debug/net8.0/YourConsoleApp.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "action": "openExternally",
                "pattern": "\\bNow listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)"
            },
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach"
        }
    ]
}
```

`tasks.json` is used to configure scripts and start processes. E.g

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "build",
                "${workspaceFolder}/YourConsoleApp/YourConsoleApp.csproj",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        },
        {
            "label": "publish",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "publish",
                "${workspaceFolder}/YourConsoleApp/YourConsoleApp.csproj",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        },
        {
            "label": "watch",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "watch",
                "run",
                "${workspaceFolder}/YourConsoleApp/YourConsoleApp.csproj",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

You can also take a look here

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/csharp/debugging

Comment: Added both of these files (customised to my project ofc) and neither worked.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, when running into this same error in VS Code on Windows, it turned out that I had the wrong version of the .NET SDK installed. You might try getting the latest update for that and see if it resolves the issue.